# How to add object within array in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I have a array object now I want to add another object inside existing array object as given below:

**Output should be like this:** `[{​a:1,b:2,c:3,d:4}​]`

```js
let a =[{a:1,b:2,c:3}];
let d={d:4}

console.log([...a,d]);
```

Comment: Note that the output you're showing is an array with a single object, being the combination of `a` and `d`. Not an array with _multiple_ objects, which is what your code is currently doing. If the output you're showing is what you want, you _don't_ want to add an object an object to an array, you want to merge `d` with `a[0]` (either as new object, or in-place)

Comment: I'm trying to achieve output like required but not able to do that...

Comment: `a[0]['d'] = 4`?

Comment: why is this an array with a single item in it? can this array have multiple items in it? what's the expected result then (for multiple objects)?

Comment: @dalelandry it's a bit weird to assume you know what `d` is in code that uses a, b, c, d, and 1, 2, 3, 4 to represent data.

Comment: OP => `Output should be like this:- [{​a:1,b:2,c:3,d:4}​]`

Comment: @RohitVerma remember that the spread operator works for objects, too. Given two objects `a` and `b`, `{...a, ...b]` gives a new object with both their key/values.

Comment: @dale landry yes i need output like same.

Comment: Perhaps OP did not give enough info, hence a comment

Comment: @dalelandry exactly, the output should be the combination of a[0] and d, and you don't know the _actual_ property names or values of either. But we also don't need to, we can combine objects based on just "having two objects". Rohit gave enough information here.

Comment: @dale landry thank you `a[0]['d'] = 4` this is working fine for me...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the shown output (single object in an array), you can spread (add) `d` into `a[0]`

```js
let a = [{a:1,b:2,c:3}];
let d={d:4}
a[0] = { ...a[0], ...d }
console.log(a);
```

---

But if you don't need a dynamic solution, I'd recommend dales way:

```
a[0]['d'] = 4
```